# for-loop call textbox.text with variable inside the name

Tags: c#, for-loop, methods, callback

How can I call textbox.text with the "I" variable from a for-loop? I have 13 Textboxes and do exactly 13 times the same thing (see my sourcecode). How can I do it simpler with a for-loop?  `TempRechnung.ReplaceText("{1_ANR}", "txtArtikel_" + i + "_Nr.Text");` Does actually not work...

My current Sourcecode:

```
// #1
if (txtArtikel_1_Epreis.Text != string.Empty)
{
    decimal Artikel_1_GP = Convert.ToDecimal(txtArtikel_1_Epreis.Text) * Convert.ToInt32(txtArtikel_1_Menge.Text);
    decimal Artikel_1_EP = Convert.ToDecimal(txtArtikel_1_Epreis.Text);
    TempRechnung.ReplaceText("{1_ANR}", txtArtikel_1_Nr.Text);
    TempRechnung.ReplaceText("{1_BEZ}", txtArtikel_1_Bez.Text);
    TempRechnung.ReplaceText("{1_ME}", txtArtikel_1_Menge.Text);
    TempRechnung.ReplaceText("{1_EP}", Artikel_1_EP.ToString("C"));
    TempRechnung.ReplaceText("{1_GP}", Artikel_1_GP.ToString("C"));
}
else
{
    TempRechnung.ReplaceText("{2_ANR}", "");
    TempRechnung.ReplaceText("{2_BEZ}", "");
    TempRechnung.ReplaceText("{2_ME}", "");
    TempRechnung.ReplaceText("{2_EP}", "");
    TempRechnung.ReplaceText("{2_GP}", "");
}

// #2
if (txtArtikel_2_Epreis.Text != string.Empty)
{
    decimal Artikel_2_GP = Convert.ToDecimal(txtArtikel_2_Epreis.Text) * Convert.ToInt32(txtArtikel_2_Menge.Text);
    decimal Artikel_2_EP = Convert.ToDecimal(txtArtikel_2_Epreis.Text);
    TempRechnung.ReplaceText("{2_ANR}", txtArtikel_2_Nr.Text);
    TempRechnung.ReplaceText("{2_BEZ}", txtArtikel_2_Bez.Text);
    TempRechnung.ReplaceText("{2_ME}", txtArtikel_2_Menge.Text);
    TempRechnung.ReplaceText("{2_EP}", Artikel_2_EP.ToString("C"));
    TempRechnung.ReplaceText("{2_GP}", Artikel_2_GP.ToString("C"));
}
else
{
    TempRechnung.ReplaceText("{2_ANR}", "");
    TempRechnung.ReplaceText("{2_BEZ}", "");
    TempRechnung.ReplaceText("{2_ME}", "");
    TempRechnung.ReplaceText("{2_EP}", "");
    TempRechnung.ReplaceText("{2_GP}", "");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest creating `Artikel` user control, which will have following textboxes inside: `Epreis`, `Nr`, `Bez` and `Menge`. Then place 13 of these user controls on your form and loop them. You can create collection of artikel controls manually, or you can query for them:

```
var artikels = Controls.OfType<ArtikelControl>();
```

Here is WinForms sample of ArtikelControl:

```
public partial class ArtikelControl : UserControl
{
    public ArtikelControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public decimal GP 
    {
        get { return Decimal.Parse(epreisTextBox.Text) *
                     Int32.Parse(mengeTextBox.Text); } // add validation
    }
    public decimal EP { get { return Decimal.Parse(epreisTextBox.Text); } }
    public string Nr { get { return nrTextBox.Text; } }
    public string Bez { get { return bezTextBox.Text; } }
    public string Menge { get { return mengeTextBox.Text; } }
    public bool HasEpreis
    { 
        get { return !String.IsNullOrEmpty(epreisTextBox.Text); } 
    }
}
```

Now if you have collection of these controls, you can loop it and get values from each control:

```
foreach(var artikel in artikels)
{
    if (artikel.HasEpreis)
    {
        TempRechnung.ReplaceText("{2_ANR}", artikel.Nr);
        TempRechnung.ReplaceText("{2_BEZ}", artikel.Bez);
        // ...
    }
    else
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```